# Print/Debug Raw SOAP Request Including Headers with Apex Webservice

Tags: apex, soap, debugging, apex-webservice

Is there any way to print the raw SOAP request for apex webservices? We have a web service that is used by a number of external providers and are putting a proxy in place that will perform some modifications of the SOAP XML. I'm hoping I can do some logging of current request to get an idea what we're in for. Is this possible?

For example if I debugged a request to this method

```
webservice static String GetMessage() {
  return 'Connected!';
}
```

I'd get something like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mag="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/Magnet">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mag:GetMessage/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a dev org, the raw soap request and response are dumped into the debug log. In any other edition they are unavailable.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in my DE org, is there something you have to do to get that?

Comment: As far as I can recall if you create the debug log the soap dump just happens.

Comment: Yep, sorry - I misread the question

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own best answer, based on some internet research:

You can use an external tool like Runscope as a webservice proxy to automatically forward requests and pass through responses and view the XML SOAP messages. This is not a native solution on SFDC but it does do the job.

https://www.runscope.com/

Comment: we ended up going a similar route by setting up a basic node proxy on heroku that we can then tie up to a log provider (we went with logentries, there are lots of alternatives), it's given us a lot of flexibility to troubleshoot issues that come up with our SOAP webservices